# Trouble installing VNC

Tags: windows-10, vnc, realvnc

I got the following error when I tried to install realVNC:

[image]

I found [some advice](https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/497/6/installation-failed-with-error-message-could-not-install-vnc-server-1603--1610) to not install Windows Mirror Driver, but the installer didn't give that option - so I tried to use the /NOMIRRORDRIVER option but with the same result.

EDIT: I got similar result for ultraVNC and tightVNC!!! There must be some principial problem!

[image]

Comment: did you see this link? https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/497/6/installation-failed-with-error-message-could-not-install-vnc-server-1603--1610

Comment: Are you local to the computer you're trying to install it on?  Did that computer have a previous version of RealVNC at some point?  And you install other (non-VNC) programs successfully?

Comment: @yoyo_fun exactly this one, yes

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes I am local. Now I noticed there is TeamViewer installed on the computer.